# Extracting a pattern from file with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, pattern-matching

[I am a beginner with PowerShell]

I want to use PowerShell to extract a specific pattern from all files under a certain directory. How do I do that?

For example, let the file content be:

```
<node1>Hello World ignore</node1> 
<wantedNode>Hello World extract
this text </wantedNode>
```

I want to extract only nodes of type  that contain "hello world" (case insensitive):

```
"Hello World extract this text"
```

Comment: why should node1 be ignored? Both nodes contain "hello world"...

Comment: That is my requirement - I want to get all nodes of type wantedNode that contain Hello World

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After googling for a while, I came up with a solution:

```
$files = gci -Recurse
foreach ($file in $files)
{
    $x = [xml] (Get-Content $file.FullName)
    foreach ($node in $x.SelectNodes("//wantedNode")) 
    {       
        if ($node.InnerText -like "*Hello World*" ) 
            { 
                Write-Host $node.InnerText
            } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the file is a proper XML document then this is pretty easy e.g.:

```
Get-ChildItem *.xml | Select-Xml '//wantedNode' | Format-List Path, @{n="Text";e={$_.Node.InnerText}}
```

If the XML docs have default namespaces this gets a bit trickier but not much.  If you need to do regex search then because the text of interest spans multiple lines you need to read the files in as a single string e.g.:

```
[IO.File]::ReadAllText("$pwd\test.xml") | 
    Select-String '(?s)(?<=\<wantedNode\>)(.*?)(?=\</wantedNode\>)' | 
    Format-List Matches
```

In PowerShell v3 this gets a bit simpler:

```
Get-Content .\test.xml -Raw | 
    Select-String '(?s)(?<=\<wantedNode\>)(.*?)(?=\</wantedNode\>)' | 
    Format-List Matches
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, I added a root node:

```
[xml]$xml=@"
<root>
<node1>Hello World ignore</node1> 
<wantedNode>Hello World extract this text</wantedNode>
</root>
"@

$xml.SelectNodes("//wantedNode[contains(.,'Hello World')]") | foreach {$_.'#text'}
```